# Connection failed to Time Capsule

Tags: time-machine, macbook-pro, imac, time-capsule

I have a time capsule that I've been using for years, as a wireless router as well as automated backups and external storage.  All of a sudden, both my Mac Book and iMac stopped being able to access the external storage, and the backups from the iMac stopped working as well, but it is still working as an internet and wireless router.  In finder, when I click on the Time Capsule drive, it says Connection Failed.  Since I see the same behavior on both computers, and it started at the same time, I am guessing the problem is on the time capsule.  Any ideas?

Comment: Try the.. click the "Connect As..." button and enter the user name and password you configured for your Time Capsule via the AirPort Utility.

Comment: That doesn't work - I don't even get a password prompt. It just says Connecting... for about a minute and then Connection Failed.  Unplugging and replugging the Time Capsule fixes the issue for a few hours, but then it happens again.

Comment: I am new on stack exchange, but I am having this same problem. Obviously this is a few years after the fact, but it seems the processor for the disk access (both internal and via USB) just dies and needs a reset (wifi and ethernet continue to function). Did you ever find a solution? I was hoping to maintain use as an ethernet shared storage until I can afford a more permanent option. I was also hoping that turning off wireless would allow it to function longer (in case it was a heat issue). I still have no explanation. It works fine after restarting, then a few hours to a couple days later it